# What is an example for which the purely functional programming approach gives better results than imperative style?

Tags: programming-languages, functional-programming

*I* have seen some questions related to functional programming on stackexchange sites which suggests it has significant popularity. *I* have some experience with it from many *years* ago in Lisp/Scheme and have seen commentary on the difference between functional and imperative/mutable approaches eg [4].

*The* wikipedia page on the *subject* says "Pure functional programming disallows side effects completely and so provides referential transparency, which makes it easier to verify, optimize, and parallelize programs, and easier to write automated tools to perform those tasks." *But* it is known to have a cost of up to a factor of $O(\log(n))$ slowdown factor [2] due to lack of mutable data structures, leading to a lot of research in functional programming datastructures that have a much different flavor than mutable approaches [3].

*Along* these lines,

> *What* is an example for which the purely functional programming approach leads to better overall results than the imperative approach?

(*Also* it seems the word "mutable" here is a bit subtle. functional languages appear to allow one to "store" data eg via balanced trees, but not later "change" it. *This* is a little different than mutability eg in java, where initial storage and later changing are nearly identical operations eg with "setter" methods on the Java objects.)

[1] [functional programming, wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)

[2] stackexchange, [efficiency of purely functional programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990464/efficiency-of-purely-functional-programming)

[3] tcs.se, [What's new in purely functional data structures since Okasaki?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1539/whats-new-in-purely-functional-data-structures-since-okasaki)

[4] [Structure and interpretation of computer programs, by Abelson & Sussman](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/)

Comment: What kind of "better results" are you after? Better performance? Smaller code?

Comment: xodarap says in his answer this question is subjective. =( on 2nd thought maybe it should be closed by _rigorous stackexchange stds_.

Comment: If you fail to modify the question to make it clearer and less subjective, then perhaps it should be closed. The reason we have standards and request that posters comply to them is to maintain the level of quality of the site.

Comment: I have removed a discussion about language issues. Please restrict meta comments to a minimum and open a thread on [meta] if need be.

Comment: I think this question (in improved form) may be better off on [programmers.SE]; please flag the question if you want us to be migrated there. It is also a good example of "not a real question" as it is subjective and it is not clear what is being asked. If you specified what "good" means (runtime or space efficiency, safety, security, ...) it would be a good question, imho.

Comment: Nota bene: "immutabilty" is indeed an overloaded notion. Some definitions allow the internal representation of values to change as long as an observer has no way to detect that change (think access via the interface of an object). Afaik, function languages make heavy use of that (and term sharing) in order to improve efficiency.

Comment: maybe someone can make a list of red flag words that seem to indicate a question is "subjective", it seems to be long and near arbitrary at times =(  ... also imho "quality" of q/a is _subjective_ itself & (attempted to be) measured by the voting system

Answer (score 8):

"Better" is obviously subjective but Evan Farrer did his [master's thesis](http://evanfarrer.blogspot.ca/2012/06/unit-testing-isnt-enough-you-need.html) on rewriting python programs into Haskell (a purely functional language) and seeing how many bugs it caught. You can read his paper, but the Haskell compiler caught many non-trivial bugs.

A less controversial example is that pure languages are more easily parallelized.

Comment: He found Haskell caught bugs because it had 'powerful' type checking, not because it was a functional language. This answer is misleading.